# How can I solve that warning

Tags: objective-c

I defined a boolean variable. It's called confirmUsername and I want to check this variable YES or NO.

```
if (self.username != usernameTextFieldText) {
    self.confirmUsername = YES;
} else {
    self.confirmUsername = NO;
}
```

Xcode give that warning

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'BOOL *' (aka 'bool *') from 'BOOL' (aka 'bool')
```

What I should do ?

Comment: It seems your declaration is wrong. It's supposed to be `BOOL confirmUsername;` without asterisk. A boolean is not an object.

Comment: Could you please show us the definition of `confirmUsername`?

Comment: Further to the error (you declared a reference to a `BOOL`) the test `self.username != usernameTextFieldText` probably does **not** do what you expect. The names suggest that the intention is to compare *strings* (`NSString *` or `char *`) but the operator `!=` will compare the *references* not the string *values* – so it will only be true if the two operands reference *exactly the same* string and not strings with the same value. To compare `NSString` use the method `isEqual:` or `isEqualToString:` (if you have `char *` C strings use the function `strcmp()`). HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare like this

```
BOOL confirmUsername;
```

instead of

```
BOOL *confirmUsername;
```